# SQL - How to format SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

How to cause simple text to appear in the results of a SELECT statement?
It would be great if something like a comment could be made to appear in the data set generated by a SELECT statement.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like

```
select 'This Is A Comment' from some_table;
```

(OR) just

```
select 'This Is A Comment';
```